# small multiple images moving toward each other in beamer

Tags: beamer, animate

I want to make custom path of clipart images and want to animate images as we will done in Powerpoint. Is there any example to do this. I attach the figure as[image: Figure]

I want to move the message(letter) toward the lock and after passing the lock the lock sign is displayed on this message(letter) after that again lock message is moving to last lock and then passing the lock gain it coverted into letter(message)

Is it possible to move the small images in the straight path. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: could you please add the "message" envelope, the lock and the "ciper text" envelope as separate images to your question? I will see then what could be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possibilities, here is one of them. Use a Ti*k*Z picture and animate a coordinate.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\begin{document}
\newcount\myx
\begin{frame}[plain]
\animate<1-51>
\animatevalue<1-51>{\myx}{51}{1}
\transduration<1-51>{0.4}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [decoration={coil,aspect=0},decorate,ultra thick,blue](0,0)--(6,0);
    \node at (\the\myx mm,{1+0.1*sin(\myx*20)}) {\parbox[c][][t]{2cm}{\tikz{\duck}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Unfortunately I did not have the pics of your locks etc., but it cannot hurt to have another duck on this site. ;-)

Comment: @marmot Pkg `animate` is not used in your example, it is rather the `animate` built-in feature of beamer.

Comment: @AlexG Thanks! I didn't know that!